# Why the MSE function has the square?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, mse

There is mse function: C = $\frac{1}{2n}$ * $\sum(length(y - a)^2)$

why not just use C = $\sum(length(y - a))$ ?

(where "length" is the vector's length, "y" - ideal network's output, "a" - current network output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about L1 norm and L2 norm. Both work for neural networks. However, they are different:

- L1 norm is better for sparsity and robust against outliers
- L2 norm is more sensitive to large errors (square those large errors)
- Their first derivative is very different. I don't want to repeat what someone has already written. Look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/159379/34623.
- How those error functions update your weight is different (gradient). This has  significant impact on your convergence in stochastic gradient decent (or something like that).
- http://www.chioka.in/differences-between-the-l1-norm-and-the-l2-norm-least-absolute-deviations-and-least-squares/

Without more information, I can't comment on how L2 norm is better (or worse) for your problem.

Comment: but this problem is solved by length function, is not it?

Comment: @DmitryNalyvaiko What do you mean by length? $length(a - b) = |a - b|$?

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad y - a = some_vector. we take the length of the some_vector to: 1) make result scalar, 2) make difference absolute

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: both can be used.

Longer answer: both measures are in active use. The first measure is based on the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry), the second one on the [taxi-cab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). Or more formally: the $L_2$ distance and the $L_1$ distance.
Which is better depends on the context. Intuitively: the Euclidean distance prefers many small/medium errors over a few big errors while the taxi-cab distance is more forgiving when it comes to a few large errors. Which one is preferable depends on the context and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: you are talking about length function, but I'm asking why result of length function should be powerd by 2?

Comment: That could be because you want to 'punish' big errors in certain training cases over the same error spread over multiple training cases. Suppose over 2 training cases one algorithm has an error of 0 and 3 respectively and another algorithm has an error of 2 for both training cases. Squaring the errors would  make the second algorithm preferable, not squaring would have the first algorithm as better. The right choice depends on the context

Comment: > Squaring the errors would make the second algorithm preferable

0^2 + 3^2 = 9;
2^2 + 2^2 = 8;

why second algorithm is preferable?

Comment: An error-score of 8 is lower than an error-score of 9, lower error-score is preferable.